# Getting a promise instead of the data i receive from pinia store

Tags: pinia, nuxt3

I have succesfully fetched data from an api into my pinia store, I am getting back the json data, when i call the action from my nuxt3 component, im getting a promise.

My store:

```
import { defineStore } from 'pinia';

export const useCountriesStore = defineStore("countries", {
  state: () => ({
    countries: [],
    isLoading: false
  }),
  actions: {
    async fetchCountries() {
      this.isLoading = true;
      const res = await fetch('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all')
      const data = await res.json();
      this.countries = data;
      console.log(data);
      this.isLoading = false;
    }
  },
  getters: {
    getCountries: (state) => state.countries
  }
})
```

My nuxt component:

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { useCountriesStore } from '@/stores/countriesStore';
  
  export default {
   setup(){
    const countriesStore =  useCountriesStore();
    const countriesData = countriesStore.fetchCountries();
    console.log(countriesData)
   }
  }

</script>
```

This is the link to my github branch: https://github.com/AbbyNyakara/CountriesDirectory/tree/add-store

p/s: I have attached a screenshot of the data when i console log my store vs component

I have tried to fetch the data from my pinia store unsuccesfully

Comment: have you tried `const countriesData = await countriesStore.fetchCountries();` ?

Comment: When i make the ` setup function async and i do as you write` , I get undefined from the console log

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a return value in action `fetchCountries`

```
async fetchCountries() {
  this.isLoading = true;
  const res = await fetch('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all')
  const data = await res.json();
  this.countries = data;
  console.log(data);
  this.isLoading = false;

  return data;
}
```

And wait for the execution using async / await

```
<script lang="ts">
  import { useCountriesStore } from '@/stores/countriesStore';
  
  export default {
   async setup(){
    const countriesStore =  useCountriesStore();
    const countriesData = await countriesStore.fetchCountries();
    console.log(countriesData)
   }
  }

</script>
```